# cant move two canvas rectangles at same time

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, pong

I asked another question today and i have another one..

but first here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pong</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x = 100;
        var y = 100;
        var xmoveFirst = 720;
        var ymoveFirst = 0;
        var xmoveSecond = 30  ;
        var ymoveSecond = 0;
        function canvas() {
            var can = document.getElementById('theCanvas');
            can.style.backgroundColor = "black";
            var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
            
            //first player
            ctx.fillStyle="white";
            ctx.fillRect(xmoveFirst,ymoveFirst,5,75);
            
            //second player
            ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
            ctx.fillRect(xmoveSecond,ymoveSecond,5,75);
            
            //first player move
            function move(event) {
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,750,750); //clear rects
                if (event.keyCode == 40) {
                    ymoveFirst+=25;
                    console.log("first,"+ymoveFirst);
                }
                
                else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
                    ymoveFirst-=25;
                    console.log("first,"+ymoveFirst);
                }
                
                else if (event.keyCode == 83) {
                    ymoveSecond +=25;
                }
                
                else if (event.keyCode==87) {
                    ymoveSecond -=25;
                }
                ctx.fillStyle="white";
                ctx.fillRect(xmoveFirst,ymoveFirst,5,75);
                ctx.fillRect(xmoveSecond,ymoveSecond,5,75);

            }
            var movement = document.addEventListener("keydown", move);
            
          
        }
      
             
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="canvas()">
    <canvas id="theCanvas" width="750" height="750"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

so each one of the rect is moving perfectly :)
but here is the problem..
I cant move them both togheter..

thanks for helping!!

Comment: You should learn object oriented javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that the browser can only handle 1 pressed key at a time. To bypass this, you need to following things:

- An array
- Two event listeners, one for the keydown and one for the keyup event.

The array will hold the currently pressed keys. In the keydown event listener you need to set the element at the same index as the id of the pressed key to true, and in the keyup eventlistener you need to set the same element to false. Example:

```
var keys = [];

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

This will make sure, that an element stays true until the key is released. You can check, if a key is currently pressed by checking the element with the same index:

```
if (keys[87]) {
    // The "W" key is pressed
}
if (keys[83]) {
    // The "S" key is pressed
}
/// ...
```

*Note: You shouldn't use `else-if`s when you check for the pressed keys.*

Comment: @NimrodNaim You need to run the canvas function multiple times, use `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame`

Comment: the main function?

edit: it didnt work can you jsfiddle that?

Comment: @NimrodNaim 1.: move never gets called, you need to call it 2.: You need to call move multiple times. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/6ekjxonh/2/